# Merging feature branch into master branch after subsequent commits?

Tags: git

Context:

I created a new feature branch and merged the current master branch into my feature branch and started working on the feature. Now someone else worked on his own feature branch and his changes have been merged into the "clean" master branch. So now I got a different version of the master branch in my feature branch that I'm working on.

How would I resolve this conflict? How would I merge my changes into the newest "clean" version of the master branch?

Comment: `git checkout master` and then `git merge feature`?

Comment: The problem is that my feature branch has not the same version of the master, since in the meantime the state of the master has been updated with another merge of a different feature branch. I hope you guys understand what i‘m trying to say.

Comment: Or run `git rebase master` in your feature branch before if you prefer a linear history but accept the consequences.

Comment: It is no problem if master change. Git would just create a merge commit.

Comment: I understand what you mean but this is a normal situation in Git.

Comment: As @dan1st said `master` can change while the feature branch is not merged. `git` knows when you began your branch from `master`. Any changes since will still be there and your commits will be appended to it if there are no conflicts. If there are, you'll have to resolve those, commit what you need to merge any conflicts, and then when you push you will see changes that were already in master and your new changes (plus any merge conflicts). Hope that helps

Comment: Thx a lot guys for clearing things up. I now understand how the workflow is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So now I got a different version of the master branch in my feature branch that I'm working on. How would I resolve this conflict?

It’s not a conflict. It’s normal Git workflow. While you are working on a branch, life on other branches goes on.

> How would I merge my changes into the newest "clean" version of the master branch?

You don’t. Just merge master into you, or rebase you onto master, and keep working.

When you are finished, do that one more time and submit your pull request (or checkout master and merge you, if you are not using pull requests).